# NativeScript getJSON malformed response

Tags: json, typescript, nativescript

Trying to get data from OMDb API, in Postman the result returns fine, while the getJSON function returns the data unstructured

I have already tried using a typed interface

```
export interface ApiResponse {
    Search: Movies[]; 
    totalResults: string;
    Response: string;
}

export interface Movies {
    title: string;
    year: number;
    poster: string;
    imdbId: string;
    type: string;
}
```

This is the getJSON code

```js
return getJSON<any>(
            this.apiUrl + this.apiKey + "&s=Harry-potter&page10"
        ).then(r => {
            console.log(r);
        });
```

which returns then json malformed

```
LOG from device : {
LOG from device : "imdbID": "tt1201607",
LOG from device : "Type": "movie",
LOG from device : "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjIyZGU4YzUtNDkzYi00ZDRhLTljYzctYTMxMDQ4M2E0Y2YxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTIzOTk5ODM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
LOG from device : },
LOG from device : {
LOG from device : "Year": "2011",
LOG from device : "Search": [
LOG from device : "Title": "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2",
LOG from device : {
LOG from device : "Title": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",
LOG from device : "Year": "2001",
LOG from device : "imdbID": "tt0241527",
LOG from device : "Type": "movie",
LOG from device : },
LOG from device : {
LOG from device : "Title": "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets",
LOG from device : "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjQ3NWNlNmQtMTE5ZS00MDdmLTlkZjUtZTBlM2UxMGFiMTU3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjUwNzk3NDc@._V1_SX300.jpg"
```

Expecting a return like this from Postman:

```
{
    "Search": [
        {
            "Title": "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2",
            "Year": "2011",
            "imdbID": "tt1201607",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjIyZGU4YzUtNDkzYi00ZDRhLTljYzctYTMxMDQ4M2E0Y2YxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTIzOTk5ODM@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",
            "Year": "2001",
            "imdbID": "tt0241527",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNjQ3NWNlNmQtMTE5ZS00MDdmLTlkZjUtZTBlM2UxMGFiMTU3XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjUwNzk3NDc@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets",
            "Year": "2002",
            "imdbID": "tt0295297",
            "Type": "movie",
            "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTcxODgwMDkxNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMDk2MDg3._V1_SX300.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "totalResults": "80",
    "Response": "True"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but casing matters. You won't get your value mapped correctly as it is written. e.g. `imdbID !== imdbId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the `console log`, use another `then`(I am pretty sure you should do it with a promise) and `resolve` the returned result as follows or `reject` in case of error. You can also add a `console log` in the catch block, to see the body of the `error`:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   fetch(
            this.apiUrl + this.apiKey + "&s=Harry-potter&page10"
        )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(r => {
            console.log(r);
            resolve(r)
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err))
})
```

The `fetch` method already returns a `Promise`, so you do not have to `return a new Promise` you can just concatenate `.then()` after the `fetch`. In my view it is fancier to use `resolve` and `reject`.
This should fix the problem.
Also see the docs for fetch in Native Script here: [Fetch](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/fetch)

Comment: Not working, res.json() is not a function...Turning the response into a JSON string gives it correct format, but then turning the string into JSON returnes the same malformed JSON...

Comment: Turns out the JSON was fine all the time, using the terminal in VS Code instead of NativeScript's Sidekick did the trick. Sorry for the inconvenience.